# Get the element by title inside repeatable class in Selenium Webdriver in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to click on an element which contains class and title in selenium python.

A webpage contains repeatable class without any id but with unique name.
I want to detect and click on this title 'PaymateSolutions' once its loads in the page.
Below is the html tag. I tried many ways but I am ending up with errors.
Fyi I cant use the find element by class as they are not unique.

```
<div class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-item" title="PaymateSolutions">
<p class="MuiTypography-root jss5152 MuiTypography-body1">PaymateSolutions</p>
</div>
```

Few approaches that i tried to get driver element based on title using XPATH

Approach 1:-

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//class[@title='PaymateSolutions']")))
```

Approach 2:-

```
element2 = (WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//p[@title='PaymateSolutions']")))

        )
```

Approach 3:-

```
element2 = (WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//[@title='PaymateSolutions']")))

        )
```

Can someone please help here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For Approach 1** - `title` is the attribute of `div` tag. So the Xpath would be something like below:

```
//div[@title='PaymateSolutions']
```

**For Approach 2** - `p` tag has no `title` attribute. `PaymateSolutions` is the `text` of the `p` tag. Xpath should be something like this:

```
//p[text()='PaymateSolutions']
```

**For Approach 3** - There is no `Tag Name` in the xpath. Xpath would be:

```
//*[@title='PaymateSolutions']
Or
//div[@title='PaymateSolutions']
```

Links to refer - [Link1](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/find-element-by-xpath-in-selenium), [Link2](https://automationpanda.com/2019/01/15/web-element-locators-for-test-automation/)

We can apply `Explicit waits` like below:

```
# Imports required for Explicit waits:
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)
payment_option = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"xpath for PaymateSolutions option")))
payment_option.click()
```

Link to refer for the Explicit waits - [Link](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Comment: Worked like a charm and the way you explained each of the flows was really very helpful.Thanks so much.

Comment: one small information needed.Do you know a way how we can give a delay to read all the html elements tag once a page loads post a click of an element..i am trying to give a implicit delay and then read the page_source but its not working

Comment: @pythonNinja -  Thank you. We can apply Explicit waits to click on Elements. But if the Website takes time to load, apply some `time.sleep(10)` after `driver.get(url)` or after click on an element. Have reupdated the answer. Go through the same.

Comment: `time.sleep()` is not recommended, but not sure of the website functionality. Hence suggesting that.

Answer (score 1):

All the XPath that you've been trying seems a bit wrong. Please use the below XPath :

```
//div[@title='PaymateSolutions']//p[text()='PaymateSolutions']
```

**Code trial 1:**

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@title='PaymateSolutions']//p[text()='PaymateSolutions']").click()
```

**Code trial 2:**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@title='PaymateSolutions']//p[text()='PaymateSolutions']"))).click()
```

**Code trial 3:**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@title='PaymateSolutions']//p[text()='PaymateSolutions']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

**Code trial 4:**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@title='PaymateSolutions']//p[text()='PaymateSolutions']")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click().perform()
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```